# Angular POS app, trying to generate an automatic purchase order from a POJO

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I'm x-referencing a few things inside of a products object, namely, stock levels, low stock levels, suppliers, min-order qty, and cost. The method should create an order object for each supplier with each product whose stock is lower than low-stock levels.

Using this object format:

```
    0: {
$$hashKey: "081",
$id: "-JPuOUmkvwpXB-99QuU6",
brand: "",
categories: Array[2],
events: Array[1],
imgUrl: "http://crayons-roleplay.weebly.com/uploads/2/4/9/6/24964708/735664_orig.jpg",
lowStock: "10",
messages: Array[1],
minOrder: "25",
name: "Crazy Crayons - Eco stars (individual)",
notes: Array[1],
price: "0.5",
quantity: "",
size: "",
sku: "912143",
stock: "21",
suppliers: [
  0: {,
  caseSize: ""
  name: "Crazy Crayons"
  price: 0.29
  sku: ""
  units: ""
  tax: "15"
  units: ""
  upc: "91214"
  updated: 1404907608273
  }
]

1: {
$$hashKey: "082"
$id: "-JPuOUmnj9r6wGx27qVE"
brand: ""
categories: Array[1]
events: Array[1]
lowStock: 0
messages: Array[1]
minOrder: 4
name: "Lifefactory 12 oz Straw Cap - Coral"
notes: Array[1]
price: "26"
quantity: ""
size: ""
sku: "45635971011"
stock: "0"
suppliers: Array[1]
  0: Object
  caseSize: ""
  name: "SOKO"
  price: 13
  sku: ""
  units: ""
  tax: ""
  units: ""
  upc: "45635971011"
  updated: "2014-07-07T17:02:49.089Z"
}

                  action:function(){
```

Making a list of products with low stock:

```
                        angular.forEach(data.products.array, function(value){
                            if(value.stock < value.lowStock){
                                if(angular.isObject(value)){
                                    $scope.generatedOrder.push({id:value.$id,upc:value.upc,'min-order':value.minOrder,supplier:value.suppliers});
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        $scope.supplierList = [];
                        $scope.supplierResults = [];
```

Pulling a list of suppliers from low-stock products:

```
                        angular.forEach($scope.generatedOrder, function(order){
                            angular.forEach(order.supplier, function(supplier){
                                if ($scope.supplierList.indexOf(supplier.name) == -1) {
                                    $scope.supplierList.push(supplier.name);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        angular.forEach($scope.supplierList, function(supplier){
                            $scope.supplierResults[supplier]=[];
                        });
```

Troublesome facet, I've tried many different ways to create an order key'd by the supplier. The closest I've come to victory is an array of supplier objects, with the right key but no value.

```
for(var i=0;i<Object.keys($scope.generatedOrder).length ;i++){
                            for(var j=0;j<$scope.supplierList.length;j++){
                                if (!angular.isArray(supplierResults[$scope.supplierList[j]])){
                                    supplierResults[$scope.supplierList[j]] = [];
                                }
                                if ($scope.generatedOrder[i].supplier !== undefined){
                                    if ( $scope.generatedOrder[i].supplier['0'].name === $scope.supplierList[j]) {
                                        supplierResults[$scope.supplierList[j]].unshift($scope.generatedOrder[i]);
                                        $scope.supplierResults = supplierResults;

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Now, this almost works. The proper objects are built up and show in the array but the array reads length: 0 so I tried to have the length of $scope.supplierResults = supplierResults in here to make the browser think the array is full and normal.

```
                        $scope.supplierResults.length = supplierResults.length;

                        console.log($scope.supplierResults);
                        return $scope.supplierResults;
```

The end result should be like `$scope.supplierResults = [{supplier:'xyz', items:[{id:'4g245t2g424g45t',name:apple, sku:453524, cost:3, qty:10}]}, {supplier:'abc',items:[{id:'3982462398uih23j',orange, sku:32545, cost:2, qty:12}]}]`

Comment: Have you ever taken a look at lodash? It's a data manipulation library that makes this kind of stuff super easy. If you're open to trying lodash I can show you how to do this kind of thing in it really quickly.

Comment: Thanks J, I'm open to learning new things but it seems this solution should be trivial with angular forEach's and if's. If that's really not the case, how would you do this with lodash?

Comment: Give me just a moment

Comment: OK I realized I just duplicated your partial success but that's not what you're looking for. Can you supply a sample of what you'd like your final result to look like? I understand the object structure at this point but would like to see an example of the desired end result. Can you edit your original question to include that? Thanks - J

Comment: edited to show my hopeful result

Comment: ok just a quick question, do you want the full object for the supplier or just its name? And items should be all items where the stock has fallen below the desired level?

Comment: the supplier property has some necessary values, like their costs and order #'s. You've got the right idea with the second part - when a user clicks the button firing this method, it first runs through all the products to return only the ones where stock < lowStock.

Comment: i've gotten a little further with my code, only the objects save to an array that reads length:0 so it's somewhat broken..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Here is updated, correct code. I accidentally left the target out of the "omit" and forgot to call value() to end my chain in the inner function right after the omit.

```
var result = _(data) 
    .filter(function(product){ 
        return product.stock < product.lowStock && _.isObject(product);
    })
    .map(function(product){ 
        return _(product.suppliers).map(function(supplier){ 
            return {supplier:supplier, product : _.omit(product, 'suppliers')}; 
        }).value();
    })
    .flatten()
    .groupBy(function(productAndSupplier){
        return productAndSupplier.supplier.name; 
    })
    .map(function(productAndSupplierGroup){
        return _(productAndSupplierGroup).reduce(function(memo, current){
            memo.supplier = current.supplier;
            memo.items.push(current.product);
            return memo;
        },{items:[]})
    })
.value();
```

And a plunkr to show it in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/XAiyWauCdKmHTS3unqO5 (note that you will have to look in the browser console to see the output)

Comment: There's an error in my first filter function I just noticed. I'll fix it in a bit, helping someone at work right now.

Comment: Very readable implementation. Thank you J. Will plug it in soon and report back. lodash seems like a very useful tool, and lightweight, too.

Comment: I installed lodash and dropped this in my directive's controller and throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8000/_DEV/mngr/directive/primary/stock.js:42:44

tried to fiddle with some variables but kept coming up with another error so haven't gotten it to work quite yet

Comment: Ok will check when I get home in an hour.

Comment: OK i knew I shouldn't have done this blind in a text editor. Two minor errors. Will have an edit in there in a few seconds that will have the corrected code.

Comment: Note that in the plunkr I cleaned up the original data a little... I changed the strings for stock and lowStock to integers, and I added some commas and other stuff to make the data actually compile. I assume your data is in good shape. If your numbers are strings, use _.parseInt to fix them in the first filter method or you'll get weird results.